# How to get a pointer type's pointed type?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have a pointer type Ptr. It might be T*, unique_ptr, shared_ptr, or others. How to get its pointed type at compilation time? I try the following but failed

```
template<class Ptr>
void f()
{
    typedef decltype(*Ptr()) T; // give unexpected results
}
```

The following deleted answer works very well.

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<Ptr>())>::type T;
```

Comment: `It might be T*, unique_ptr, shared_ptr, or others` - how? Polymorphism or templates?

Comment: @icepack scoped_ptr or other smart pointers. Only need to know its static type (compiler time).

Comment: @user1899020 The problem is that `Ptr` can be something that doesn't have a dereference operator.

Comment: @Jason Then it wouldn't be a pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure why that answer was deleted either, but the problem is that when `Ptr` is (say) `int*`, `decltype(*Ptr())` works out to `int&`. The fact that it's a reference was probably breaking compilation elsewhere.

Comment: @jrok But the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: @Jason It knows when a type doesn't have prefix `operator*` and it'll error out. That's what OP wants.

Comment: @jrok Yes, the compiler would error after it tries to instantiate the template for something that wasn't a pointer, but I personally think it's better to give the compiler more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in the middle of writing up this answer when I saw someone else had already posted it, so I gave up. But then that other answer disappeared, so here it is. If the original reappears, I'll delete this.

If `Ptr` is (for example) `int*`, then `decltype(*Ptr())` evaluates to `int&` rather than `int`, which is probably the cause of your error (whatever it is). Try:

`std::remove_reference<decltype(*Ptr())>::type`

Or, if it's possible `Ptr` might not have a default constructor:

`std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<Ptr>())>::type`

Comment: Tried. At least need a `()` after `Ptr`, like `std::remove_reference<decltype(*Ptr)>::type`. May be a typo. Your analysis is very good.

Comment: @user1899020 Yup; thanks for fixing that. Does that solve the problem or do you still have errors with certain types?

Comment: All are okay now. Thanks.

Comment: This seems not very reliable, because if `Ptr` is `void*`, dereferencing `void *` is not allowed.

Answer (score 12):

This is one way to do it.

Create a helper class, with appropriate specializations to deduce the pointer type.

```
template <typename T> Pointer;

template <typename T> Pointer<T*>
{
   typedef T Type;
};

template <typename T> Pointer<shared_ptr<T>>
{
   typedef T Type;
};

template <typename T> Pointer<unique_ptr<T>>
{
   typedef T Type;
};

template<class Ptr>
void f()
{
    typedef typename Pointer<Ptr>::Type PointerType;
}
```

Comment: could you post an example of how this is used ?
for instance i have a function called from some 3rd party library 

SomeCallBack(void* data) {  }  

i want to know what type i need to cast data to

Comment: @eranotzap, my suggested solution won't work for `void*`.